# Python 2.7 Beautiful Soup- parsing list of links

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse all of the links on this page which have an identical hierarchy.  I am not getting any traceback, but not getting the data either.

I am trying to get the href tag from the highlighted portion of code:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/BQTzONo.jpg]

My current code is:

```
def link_parser(soup,itemsList):
for item in soup.findAll("div", { "class" : "tileInfo" }):
    for link in item.findAll("a", { "class" : "productClick productTitle" }):
        try:
            itemsList.put(removeNonAscii(html_parser.unescape(link.string)).replace(',',' ')+","+clean_a_url(link['href']))
        except Exception:
            print "Formatting error: "
            traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)

return ""
```

Comment: you should not give image links. it's not possible to `copy-paste` from images.

Comment: What data do you need ? Why `removeNonAscii` and `clean_a_url` ? And you don't need to unescape html-encoded strings, BeautifulSoup already does that for you, you can access the unescaped text using `link.text`.

Comment: I need the href from this tag:
 <a class="productClick productTitle" id="prodTitle-medium-1-1" href="this_is_what_i_need" title="Skylanders" name =prodTitle_207736493">

I use clean_a_url because I need the url's to be consistent and clean.  I use removeNonAscii because sometimes there are NonAscii characters in the url's I work with.

Can you show me an example of accessing the unescaped text using link.text?

Comment: @user3677501 define "consistent and clean". If the original URL has non-ASCII characters and you remove them the URL will be broken since the website still expects its original non-ASCII URL. Simply use `link.text`, like `somelist.put(link.text)` or `print(link.text)`.

Comment: @AndreDaniel
You're right, I appreciate the critique.
I tried itemsList.put(link.text), however it's still not filling my List with url's.  Would you mind taking a look at my specific situation and making a recommendation on where to proceed?

Comment: If you want the URL then it's not the text, it's the link's `href` attribute, accessible via `link["href"]` (assuming the attribute exists, otherwise an exception will be raised).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you were trying to scrape Target's website - perhaps [this page](http://www.target.com/c/action-figures-sets-playsets-toys/-/N-5xt87).

You've encountered one of the fundamental difficulties with web page scraping - what you see is *not* always what you get.  In this case they are AJAXing in a bunch of content after you load the page.  Notice the little pinwheel animation when you first load the page - the content you were trying to access simply does not exist in the DOM until all the various js scripts they've got on that page run.  (and they've got a *whole lot* of them)

I clicked through a bit and it looks like the code responsible for generating that content is this bit of jquery:

```
   <script id="productTitleTmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" >
        {{if $item.parent.parent.viewType != "details"}}
            {{tmpl($data.itemAttributes) "#productBrandTmpl"}}
        {{/if}}
        <a class="productClick productTitle" id="prodTitle-{{= $item.parent.parent.viewType}}-{{= $item.parent.parent.currentPageNumber}}-{{= $item.parent.productCounter}}" href="/{{= productDetailPageURL}}#prodSlot={{= $item.parent.parent.viewType}}_{{= $item.parent.parent.currentPageNumber}}_{{= $item.parent.productCounter}}" title="{{= title}}" name="prodTitle_{{= $item.catalogEntryId}}">
            {{= $item.parent.parent.fetchProductTitleForView($item.productTitle)}}
        </a>
```

So, anyway.  If you *really* are dead-set on scraping this page, you will need to ditch `urllib` (or whatever you were using to fetch the html).  Instead visit this page with a javascript-enabled headless browser (like `selenium`), let the javascript run, and then scrape it.  All of that is outside the realm of this answer but you can google around for various headless browser solutions and find one that works for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for researching my issue, roippi, and not making me waste more time on this page with urllib.  I'll get to work on headless browser solutions.  I really appreciate your answer.